# How to bind keypress event in jquery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

As you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/hn838/4/ 'click' is working fine for autofiller, But I want to trigger same code on enter key keypress also, but it is not working for me. My code is here for both.
Click :

```
$('.ui-autocomplete').on('click', '.ui-menu-item', function(){
    $('.college').trigger('click');
});
```

Keyprss :

```
 $('.ui-autocomplete').on('keypress', '.ui-menu-item', function(e){
            if (e.which == 13) {
                         e.preventDefault();
            $('.college').trigger('click');
           }
        });
```

I want  `$('.college').trigger('click');` execution on `click` and enter `keypress`. click is working fine but keypress in not working.any clue ?

Comment: Since there's some confusion: Can you, please, tell us wether you really want to handle the actual keypress or the selection of an element from the list, which makes more sense.

Comment: selection of an element from the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than binding to key events, you could add a function to the [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) event:

```
select: function(){
    $('.college').trigger('click');
}
```

That way it'd only trigger when the user actually selected the autocomplete value.

http://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/hn838/10/

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Using select: function(e,item){...} lets OP do exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

There is no class `ui-autocomplete` inside your fiddle. So I assume it looks like this:

```
<input type = 'text' class = 'search ui-autocomplete' />
```

and also there is no class `ui-menu-item` in your fiddle, so you should do like this:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete').on('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.college').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hn838/6/)**

---

If you want to use the class that automatically generated from jQuery UI, you can do:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').on('keypress', function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.college').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hn838/9/)**

Comment: @pandit Can you check again? it's `ui-autocomplete-input` not `ui-autocomplete`

Comment: you removed '.ui-menu-item' how can i track in this code that which <li> ui-menu-item  is pressed ?

Comment: @pandit Sorry but where is your `.ui-menu-item` element? You target it in `on` function but I cannot find where's this element in your fiddle.

Comment: your second fiddle is exactly match with my requirements. thanks for your effort and time..

Comment: anyway when you enter something in input field than a ul is created with suggestions in li's which have class .ui-menu-item, I am refering that...

Comment: I cannot understand in which way this is answering your problem